# How do I configure Ubuntu UFW through Puppet?

Tags: puppet, hiera, ufw

I am quite new to Puppet and I am having some problems with the Puppet Config for one of our hosts running Puppet Agent.
We are using Ubuntu 20.04 and Puppet CE 7.12.1 on all systems.

On our Puppet Server (Hostname: `puppet`), I am trying to write the Puppet config for our host `eb-web` (which is running a Puppet Agent).
I would like to configure UFW (Uncomplicated Firewall) (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) on `eb-web` using the Puppet Module `kogitoapp/ufw` version 1.0.3 (https://forge.puppet.com/modules/kogitoapp/ufw) to allow through HTTP traffic.

Our Puppet Server is configured to use Hiera to hold our facts. So far I have created the following configuration files:
File: `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hiera.yaml`

```
version: 5
defaults:
  # The default value for "datadir" is "data" under the same directory as the hiera.yaml
  # file (this file)
hierarchy:
  - name: "Per-node data (yaml version)"
    path: "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}.yaml"
  - name: "Per-role data"
    path: "roles/%{::role}"
  - name: "Other YAML hierarchy levels"
    paths:
      - "common.yaml"
```

File: `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/data/common.yaml`

```
# empty at the moment
```

File:
`/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp`

```
node default {
  hiera_include('roles')
}
```

File: `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/data/nodes/eb-web.evolvedbinary.com.yaml`

```
roles:
   - roles::www

ufw::ufw_rule:
  name: 'Allow HTTP'
  action: allow
  to_ports_app: 80
  proto: tcp
```

File: `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/roles/manifests/www.pp`

```
class roles::www {
    include profiles::ufw
    # include profiles::nginx
}
```

File: `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/profiles/manifests/ufw.pp`

```
class profiles::ufw {
  class{ '::ufw': }
}
```

I have also installed the ufw module on the Puppet Server by running:

`sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet module install kogitoapp-ufw --version 1.0.3`

---

If I now switch to the `eb-web` host and try and ask the Puppet Agent to apply the config from the Puppet Server by running:

`sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --no-daemonize --test`

Then I see the following output which I think is showing that everything was applied:

```
ubuntu@eb-web:~$ sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --no-daemonize --test
Info: Using environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for eb-web.evolvedbinary.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1639003464'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.60 seconds
ubuntu@eb-web:~$
```

After this if I check: `sudo ufw status`, it seems to indicate that port 80 for HTTP has NOT been configured by Puppet:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

---

---

“Update (20-Dec-2021)”

After trying a solution to this issue, I got this working, however, I made a mistake and added the rules into the `ufw.pp file`, this was not the way right way I wanted to do this. After taking the rules out of the `ufw.pp` file and just having them in the `eb-web.evolvedbinary.com.yaml` file the `ufw port 80` is now being rejected. I have tried using `status: enable` and `status: allow` , I have also tried `ensure: present` , along with trying other combinations that I cannot remember 100%, all with in the `eb-web.evolvedbinary.com.yaml` file. The `ufw.pp` file currently looks like:

```
class profiles::ufw {
  class{ 'ufw':
 } 
}
```

And the `eb-web.evolvedbinary.com.yaml` file looks like:

```
---
roles:
   - roles::www
ufw::rule:
  'Allow HTTP':
    action: allow
    to_ports_app: 80
    proto: tcp
include nginx:
nginx::nginx_server:
   'www.evolvedbinary.com':
   ssl: true
   www_root: '/var/www/www.evolvedbinary.com'
```

I am not seeing any errors when I run `sudo /opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet agent --no-daemonize --test` on the `eb-web` host (puppet agent) however, when I run `sudo ufw status` I see:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                   # allow_puppet
80                         REJECT      Anywhere                   # Allow HTTP
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)              # allow_puppet
80 (v6)                    REJECT      Anywhere (v6)              # Allow HTTP
```

I am not sure how I can enable port 80 using `hiera` within the `eb-web.evolvedbianry.com.yaml` file.

Can someone help me figure out how to configure UFW using Puppet please?

Comment: Correct terminology is important for reading and understanding docs and communicating with others.  To that end, no, you are *not* using Hiera to hold facts.  Facts are provided directly by nodes as part of their catalog requests.  Hiera holds data that pertain to your site and maybe to specific nodes, but these data are not facts.  In particular, they can neither be accessed directly as top-scope variables nor via the `$facts` hash.  And on the other hand, automatic data binding such as you are trying to use relies on hiera data, not facts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time spent trying to work this out and going back and fourth with why this was not working. I finaly relised my mistake in the `eb-web.evolvedbinary.com.yaml`. I needed to add `include ufw` and also change `ufw::rule` to `ufw::rules`. After these these changes where done port 80 is now working.
The `eb-web.evolvedbinary.com.yaml` file now looks like:

```
---
roles:
   - roles::www
include ufw:
ufw::rules:
   'Allow HTTP':
      action: allow
      to_ports_app: 80
      proto: tcp
include nginx:
nginx::nginx_server:
   'www.evolvedbinary.com':
   ssl: true
   www_root: '/var/www/www.evolvedbinary.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

This Hiera data ...

> ```
> ufw::ufw_rule:
>   name: 'Allow HTTP'
>   action: allow
>   to_ports_app: 80
>   proto: tcp
> ```

... appears to be an attempt to declare an instance of the module's `ufw_rule` resource type within your hiera data.  You cannot declare resources that way (and that resource type is a plugin type whose name is `ufw_rule`, not `ufw::ufw_rule`).  Resource declarations go in your manifests. For example, you might put this in `profiles/manifests/ufw.pp`:

```
ufw_rule { 'Allow HTTP':
  action       => 'allow',
  to_ports_app => 80,
  proto        => 'tcp',
}
```

Hiera's most prominent use is in providing data for class (but not resource) parameters, and some classes use this to support indirect resource declaration.  You generally put data representing one or more resources into a class parameter, and then declaring that class results in it declaring the resources so described.  The `ufw` class you are using provides this option via its parameter `rules` (note spelling), which expects data in the form of a hash of hashes with resource name keys at the outer level and resource name / value mappings for `ufw_rule` resources at the inner level.  If you want to make use of that, then the data would be structured like this:

```yaml
ufw::rules:
  'Allow HTTP':
    action: allow
    to_ports_app: 80
    proto: tcp
```

Of course, you can also assign parameter values directly in your class declarations, as your other answer demonstrates, but this requires using resource-like class declarations.  Resource-like class declarations should be avoided wherever possible.  Prefer `include`, `require`, or `contain` for declaring classes.

Comment: I'm glad that helped, @CallumMcCrorie.  Do please consider reviewing [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing would be to look at the examples on the Puppet forge https://forge.puppet.com/modules/kogitoapp/ufw#basic and I'd probably put hiera to one side for the time being to make debugging easier.

Try putting this in `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/profiles/manifests/ufw.pp`

```
class profiles::ufw {
  class {'ufw':
    rules => {
      'Allow HTTP' => {
        'action'       => 'allow',
        'to_ports_app' => 80,
        'proto         => 'tcp',
      },
    }
  }
}
```